# mysql multiple table query inside php loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Faily new to php and mysql, this will probably seem very messy.

This is what I came up with:

```
$query = "show tables like 'whatever%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ". $row[0] ." WHERE a=(SELECT MAX(a)) AND b=(SELECT MAX(b)) AND c LIKE 'd%' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"); 


while($info=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
  echo "...";
}
}
```

I get the desired value from each table, so x results depending on the amount of tables. What I would like is to have the results of the queried tables but only show the top 10-5 ordered by date/time.

Is this possible with the current script? Is there an easier way (while, number of tables changing constantly)? Is this query method database intensif?

Cheers!

Comment: what is the goal here?  echo (no concern for storing in php var) some fields from the X most recent rows meeting the max conditions from any of tables that begin with 'whatever'?

Comment: If x=100 tables, I get a value(s)/output per table, I only want 10 out of the 100 tables, the 10 being the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call constantly changing number of tables having similar structure a design error. also query switch to

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE c LIKE 'd%' ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC, date DESC LIMIT 1");
```

is a little relief to database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. Certain pages on my site act as mini databases, when a page is loaded the table corresponding to page is queried. I did have a single table but was worried that querying a massive amount of data every time a page is loaded was not good thing, i.e my problem. Unless of course a single table doesn't have a massive effect on efficienty?

Comment: Good read, the "ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC," was very helpful, thank you!